# To Create Software to Access SMS Backup on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I have a crazy idea. I have read that accessing SMS messages from code for iPhone is impossible.
But is there a way to bypass this? I would like to write a piece of software which accesses user's SMS messages and shows some analytics.
I have read that it is possible for iPhone user to make SMS backups.
And here my question comes: can a user somehow set automatic SMS backup to somewhere (e.g. iCloud or Desktop), so that I can write software which will automatically read that backup and show some analytics?
Let's assume that the iPhone user doesn't mind to give my software access to his SMS messages backup.

Comment: "I have read that accessing SMS messages from code for iPhone is impossible." - whoever told you that either doesn't know jack about iOS or is intentionally hiding the truth. And yay, SMS backups go straight to the iTunes directory on the user's computer.

Comment: You mean that it is possible to access SMS messages for iOS from code? I have spent an hour in the Internet reading the opposite...

Comment: @userXXX Because people are being too official. If you have a jailbroken phone, sufficient experience with using `class-dump` and the MobileSubstrate API, then you can do practically anything you want. The SMS database is on the phone, after all (at a well-known location). The SMS app reads it. **Somewhere** there must be **some** code that reads it. And that code can be hooked and reused by dynamic loading and runtime introspection.

Comment: It IS impossible to do without violating Apples rules, (using undocumented APIs) and therefore impossible to do in a way which will enable you to deploy to the App store, and so in a sense what you have read is spot on. Is this people being 'too official'? Perhaps..  Perhaps some people see little sense pursuing something they won't ever be able to distribute and monetize..

Keep thinking, there are still a million great ideas to be had with the iPhone. This unfortunately is not one of em :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure those backups are encrypted anyway @H2CO3, so it is unlikely they could do anything with them anyway.

Comment: @Jef "won't ever be distributable" is not even a small lie. it's a downright wrong assertion. Have you ever heard of this thingy called "Cydia"? Hundreds of developers make a living making jailbroken apps.

Comment: @ProgrammingThomas Naw. 1. The SMS database on the device is not encrypted, 2. iTunes' backup is only encrypted when the user explicitly requires it (which is rare, some people don't even know it can be encrypted).

Comment: Thanks, cydia eh?. I might look into that lol..  'lie' seems a little over the top to me

Comment: @H2CO3 , what do you think, is it possible to make software which automatically reads SMS back-ups and processes them? What kind of software should it be: OSX program, iPhone app or something else?

Comment: @user1460819 As I've explained above: yes, I think it's possible. Either in the form of an iOS app/twea or as an OS X application.

Answer (score -1):

Apple uses a technique called sandboxing.  An app can only access it's own files.  Your app can only access it's files in it's own application directory.  The SMS database is not in your apps directory.  The SMS messages cannot be accessed on a non-jailbroken phone.  (Apple is getting better at protecting against jailbreaks).

Comment: Yeah, I know this. My idea is to somehow set some back-up settings and to process SMS backups instead of direct processing iPhone SMS (which I cannot access). The question is more about whether such a bypassing technique is feasible and (if yes) how to implement it.

Comment: This is wrong for the reasons I've explained above. OP doesn't need yet another "not possible" non-answer.